# Flink 1.13.2: `ProducerFencedException: Producer attempted an operation with an old epoch`

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, kafka-consumer-api, flink-streaming

Runtime stack trace:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.ProducerFencedException: Producer attempted an operation with an old epoch. Either there is a newer producer with the same transactionalId, or the producer's transaction has been expired by the broker.
Wrapped by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Cannot perform send because at least one previous transactional or idempotent request has failed with errors.
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager.failIfNotReadyForSend(TransactionManager.java:356) ~[blob_p-3e1bed3b7a4fb56d21c565450551e0d96f8672ee-9f70978daf089fff4ee019a801de7cae:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:926) ~[blob_p-3e1bed3b7a4fb56d21c565450551e0d96f8672ee-9f70978daf089fff4ee019a801de7cae:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:865) ~[blob_p-3e1bed3b7a4fb56d21c565450551e0d96f8672ee-9f70978daf089fff4ee019a801de7cae:?]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internals.FlinkKafkaInternalProducer.send(FlinkKafkaInternalProducer.java:133) ~[blob_p-3e1bed3b7a4fb56d21c565450551e0d96f8672ee-9f70978daf089fff4ee019a801de7cae:?]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer.invoke(FlinkKafkaProducer.java:915) ~[blob_p-3e1bed3b7a4fb56d21c565450551e0d96f8672ee-9f70978daf089fff4ee019a801de7cae:?]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer.invoke(FlinkKafkaProducer.java:99) ~[blob_p-3e1bed3b7a4fb56d21c565450551e0d96f8672ee-9f70978daf089fff4ee019a801de7cae:?]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.TwoPhaseCommitSinkFunction.invoke(TwoPhaseCommitSinkFunction.java:223) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSink.processElement(StreamSink.java:54) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(CopyingChainingOutput.java:71) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    ... 23 more
Wrapped by: org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.ExceptionInChainedOperatorException: Could not forward element to next operator
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(CopyingChainingOutput.java:88) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:46) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:26) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.BroadcastingOutputCollector.collect(BroadcastingOutputCollector.java:75) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.BroadcastingOutputCollector.collect(BroadcastingOutputCollector.java:32) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:50) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:28) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.TimestampedCollector.collect(TimestampedCollector.java:50) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
```

My Java Flink code that sets up the Kafka Sink on a Flink DataStream.

```java
        Properties kafkaProperties = new Properties();
        // Kafka broker has TLS security enabled.
        kafkaProperties.setProperty(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, "SSL");
        kafkaProperties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaBroker);
        kafkaProperties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.TRANSACTION_TIMEOUT_CONFIG, "900000");

        var sink = dataStream.addSink(new FlinkKafkaProducer<>(
                topic,
                new KafkaStringStringPairSerializer(topic),
                kafkaProperties,
                FlinkKafkaProducer.Semantic.EXACTLY_ONCE));
        sink.name(String.format("kafka-%s", topic));
```

FYI, this is Flink 1.13.2. This is running under Amazon's Kinesis Analytics Flink runtime (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisanalytics/latest/java/what-is.html)

Comment: Was there another task running to sink data to the same Kafka broker?

Comment: Yes. There are four streams going to the same kafka broker, but different topics. Is that ok?

Comment: It seems like `transactional.id` clash. You configure your Flink Kafka producer with exactly once semantic, and you have multiple Flink jobs writing to the same Kafka broker, please make sure that `Task names` and `Operator UIDs` of the Kafka sinks are unique across these jobs.

Comment: If I switch from EXACTLY_ONCE to AT_LEAST_ONCE this issue goes away. Ideally, I'd avoid duplicate output records, but I can tolerate it for now.

Comment: Yeah, This issue only happens with EXACTLY_ONCE.